# What subgroup of $Sym(X)$ is generated by the elements of order $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, infinite-groups

Given a set, $X$, let $H(X)$ denote the subgroup of $Sym(X)$ generated by the elements of order $2$.

- If $X$ is finite, $Sym(X)$ is generated by transpositions, so $H(X)=Sym(X)$.
- I think that $H(X)=Sym(X)$ when $X$ is uncountable, too. The argument essentially comes to down to showing that one can construct a permutation of each possible cycle type.
- If $X$ is countably infinite, I think $H(X)$ contains every element with the following property $(\star)$: When $\sigma$ is expressed as the product of (possibly infinitely many) disjoint cycles, none of these cycles is co-finite. I suspect that either $H(X)=Sym(X)$ or $H(X)=\{\sigma:\sigma\text{ satisfies }\star\}$, but I haven't found a way to determine which case it is. For example, I haven't determined whether $H(\mathbb{Z})$ contains the permutation $n\mapsto n+1$ (which does not satisfy $\star$).

So, my questions are: Does $H(X)=Sym(X)$ for all $X$? And, if not, what do the exceptions look like?

Comment: Onofri proved in 1929 that the normal subgroup generated by every element of infinite support in $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbf{N})$ is the whole group. Since there's an element of infinite support of each possible order, it follows that for each $n\ge 2$ including $\infty$, $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbf{N})$ is generated by elements of order $n$ (and even by each fixed conjugacy class unless it consists of finitely supported permutations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every cycle is the product of two elements of order two.

In particular, let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be the permutations $n \mapsto n+1$, and $n \mapsto -n$ of ${\mathbb Z}$, respectively.

Then (composing from left to right), $\sigma\tau$ is $n \mapsto -n-1$, and $\sigma = (\sigma\tau)\tau$, where $\sigma\tau$ and $\tau$ both have order $2$.

Comment: Haha, so simple!  Thanks :)

Comment: What about non-cycles? We can write any $\sigma\in Sym(X)$ as a product of (possibly infinitely many) disjoint cycles: $\sigma=\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}\sigma_\alpha$. For each $\alpha$, let $\tau_\alpha,\rho_\alpha$ be permutations of order 2 such that $\tau_\alpha\rho_\alpha=\sigma_\alpha$ and the supports of $\tau_\alpha$ and $\rho_\alpha$ are contained in the support of $\sigma_\alpha$. Let $\tau=\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}\tau_\alpha$, $\rho=\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}\rho_\alpha$. Then $|\tau|=|\rho|=2$ and $\tau\rho=\sigma$. So, every element of $Sym(X)$ is the product of $2$ elements of order $2$.

Comment: Yes that's fine. In general the product of infinitely many permutations is not defined, but it's OK if they all have disjoint support.

Comment: Beware that the cycles are disjoint, but when you write them as product of 2 elements of order 2, you go outside the cycle. So the argument is not complete (although it should be fixable).